# Embed SVG font glyph in a standalone HTML file

Tags: html, css, svg, font-face

I want to use a single glyph from [Font Awesome](http://fontello.com/) in an HTML file. I want to create the HTML file with no external dependencies, so I would like the `style` `@font-face` declaration and the SVG definition of the character to be integral parts of the HTML file.

Here's what I have tried ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h9u2f7ru/)), but the custom glyph does not appear:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
  <style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: "Custom";
      src: local("Custom"), url("fonts.svg#font") format("svg");
    }
    a {
      text-decoration: none;
      font-family: Custom;
    }
  </style>  
</head>

<body>
<svg
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  display="none">

  <defs>
    <font id="font">
      <font-face font-family="Custom" />
      <glyph
        glyph-name="undo"
        unicode="@"
        d="m857 350q0-87-34-166t-91-137-137-92-166-34q-96 0-183 41t-147 114q-4 6-4 13t5 11l76 77q6 5 14 5 9-1 13-7 41-53 100-82t126-29q58 0 110 23t92 61 61 91 22 111-22 111-61 91-92 61-110 23q-55 0-105-20t-90-57l77-77q17-16 8-38-10-23-33-23h-250q-15 0-25 11t-11 25v250q0 24 22 33 22 10 39-8l72-72q60 57 137 88t159 31q87 0 166-34t137-92 91-137 34-166z" horiz-adv-x="857.1" />
    </font>
  </defs>
</svg>

<a href="#undo">@</a>
</body>
</html>
```

What have I omitted or got wrong? Or am I trying to do something that is not supported?

Answer (score 3):

What browser are you using to do this? Your fiddle works fine in Safari.

Check out this from MDN though https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/SVG_fonts

> SVG Fonts are currently supported only in Safari and Android Browser.
>   Internet Explorer hasn't considered implementing this, the
>   functionality has been removed from Chrome 38 (and Opera 25) and
>   Firefox has postponed its implementation indefinitely to concentrate
>   on WOFF. Other tools however like the Adobe SVG Viewer plugin, Batik
>   and parts of Inkscape support SVG font embedding

Comment: Ah. OK. It's good to know that I had got the syntax right : )

Comment: @JamesNewton Try downloading the Font Awesome code and just taking out the bits of it that you don't need. It uses css to add content to `:before`, so it works across multiple browsers, and then you can just implement your icon as per the Font Awesome instructions.